# php preg_match find all lines which have match

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

The string is:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=350000
128/prog_index.m3u8?key=2dd12d6d79fa163d539952ec25c6c969&app=com.dcom&part=1-1
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=500000
256/prog_index.m3u8?key=2dd12d6d79fa163d539952ec25c6c969&app=com.dcom&part=1-1
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=750000
500/prog_index.m3u8?key=2dd12d6d79fa163d539952ec25c6c969&app=com.dcom&part=1-1
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1000000
750/prog_index.m3u8?key=2dd12d6d79fa163d539952ec25c6c969&app=com.dcom&part=1-1
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1250000
1000/prog_index.m3u8?key=2dd12d6d79fa163d539952ec25c6c969&app=com.dcom&part=1-1
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1750000
1500/prog_index.m3u8?key=2dd12d6d79fa163d539952ec25c6c969&app=com.dcom&part=1-1
```

And I want to find all **prog_index.m3u8** urls. My code is:

```
preg_match_all('/(.*?)prog_index.m3u8(.*?)/mis', $get, $found);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it without regex:

```
$result = array_filter(explode("\n", $get), function ($i) {
    return $i[0] != '#' &&
      array_pop(explode('/', parse_url($i, PHP_URL_PATH))) == 'prog_index.m3u8'; 
});
```

In this way you can be sure that the line is a URL with `prog_index.m3u8` as filename.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

```
preg_match_all('/^\d+.*prog_index.m3u8.*/mi', $get, $found);
print_r($found);
```

Basically include all lines that start with a number, but stop matching at the end of the line (thus the /mi instead of /mis).